# Asp.NET MVC 6, TagHelper "asp-for" to Model itself

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tagbuilder

Lets say I have this partial View:

```
@model DateTime?
<input asp-for="???" class="form-control" />
```

What goes to ??? to bind to the Model its self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like asp-for tag helper sets the "name" and the "value" attributes of an input html tag. If your model is a simple type or a complex type that behaves like a value type such as string or DateTime?, asp-for helper fails at setting the "name" attribute. So your options are:

```
@model DateTime?
<input name="mytime" value="@Model" class="form-control" />
```

And the controller:

```
public IActionResult ReadMyForm(DateTime? mytime)
{
    // Do your thing...
    return Ok();
}
```

Or if you insist on using asp-for, then you can employ a little hack:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    var mytime = Model;
}
<input asp-for="@mytime" class="form-control" />
```

Better late than never, I guess :)